# No input text value via JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I use JavaScript to create input text fields. And everything works fine, except attribute value. It simply doesn't generate and I don't know why?

Here's my code:

```
k=1;
function addtxt() {
    var tip = document.createElement("input");
    tip.type = "text";
    tip.name = "tip[" + k + "]";
    tip.value = "Question1";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "Question: " + tip.outerHTML + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(div);
k++
}
```

This is what I got:

```
<input type="text" name="tip[1]">
```

Comment: What is the problem i don't understood what you are trying tosay

Comment: There is no attribute "value". I defined it to be in this example "Question 1" and it simply doesn't generate. It should be something like <input type="text" name="tip[1]" value="Question1">

Comment: provide jsfiddle for the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be try using setAttribute(), like, change:

```
tip.value = "Question1";
```

to

```
tip.setAttribute('value', "Question1");
```